# Can't Launch app on iOS Simulator in Xamarin Studio Mac

Tags: xamarin, ios-simulator, provisioning-profile, xamarin-studio, ios-provisioning

Been tinkering with [Hanselman.Forms](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms) on my Mac with Android. Today I decided it was time to try it on the iOS Simulator...

I have serious regrets about this decision.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm able to deploy an app from Xcode to the iOS Simulator just fine. Just won't work from Xamarin Studio.

In all fairness I do get an error:
No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys.

I do see this "error" in Xcode as well, but it doesn't prevent me from launching the app there.

Thanks.

Comment: Setting up provisioning reference: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/device_provisioning/offline.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing entries from **Entitlements.plist** worked. I also had to delete the original device Xamarin Studio was trying to deploy to. After I did, Xamarin Studio created another device and launched the application successfully.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/117465#Comment_117465

Answer (score 2):

To the exact error message:

> No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities

1. <kbd>control</kbd> *click* Xamarin Studio > Solution > Project.iOS
2. Options > **Build** > iOS Bundle Signing > Custom Entitlements
3. Select and **delete** `Entitlements.plist` text entry. In other words, do *not* click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button to select new new file, nor bother editing the entitlements by hand)
4. OK, Build > Rebuild All.

Comment: What if I need the Entitlements to be there?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same when I was trying to deploy to the simulator without a physical device configuration.  My fix was to:

- Close Visual Studio
- Open the .csproj in NOTEPAD
- Find the line with `CodesignElements` and delete it
- Save the .csproj
- Reopen the project in Visual Studio
- Right-mouse your IOS project and click "Rebuild
  All", you should see "2 Succeeded"
- Give it a run, and your app will come up on your Mac

Good discussion of this here  -
   http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39534/cant-build-ios-in-xamarin-studio-5-7-1-through-5-9

Good luck