# Could not find any available provisioning profiles for Xamarin iOS app in Visual Studion 2019

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I have created a simple Xamarin iOS app that uses firebase authentication. In firebase I have enabled Email/Password authentication. I have used this code for user registration by click of a button:

```
Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password, (AuthDataResult authresult, NSError error) => {
    if(error == null)
    {
        var user = authresult.User;

        if(user != null)
        {
            var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Alert", "Registration was Successful", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Error", error.LocalizedDescription, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
        PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }
});
```

I have enabled **Keychain** in  **Entitlements.plist** and included it for **Custom Entitlement** in **info.plist** as follows:

[image]

I am unable to see any provisioning profile. I just need to run this app on iOS Simulator and not on a real device. So when I build, it says **Could not find any available provisioning profiles**. I am even unable to create a provisioning profile in Xcode, I get this error.

[image]

I actually want to run this app on the simulator and I am really stuck on this. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you added your apple developer account in the Visual-Studio? BTW, have a look at these threads may help: [Can't find provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620026/xamarin-forms-cant-find-provisioning-profile-ios-bundle-signing) and [Can't Launch app on iOS Simulator in Xamarin Studio Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689877/cant-launch-app-on-ios-simulator-in-xamarin-studio-mac).

Comment: For me, removing "Entitlements.plist" from the Custom Entitlements field in iOS Bundle Signing did the trick, under project options. You said you don't have any provisioning profiles and just want to run on the simulator which is what I was trying to do. But there was a custom Entitlements.plist that was causing that message to appear.